# Create EC public key from qx and qy in OpenSSL 3

Tags: openssl

OpenSSL 1 one has a method to set EC public key components qx and qy. OpenSSL 3 doesn't have corresponding method. EVP_PKEY_fromdata() doesn' accept qx and qy parameters, but public key as a single value.
How one can create EC public key from qx and qy in OpenSSL 3 using recommended (non-deprecated) functions?

I tried using EVP_PKEY_fromdata, read openssl sources just to find qx and qy are only gettable and not settable.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to build up the point for public key, and use `EVP_PKEY_fromdata()` with `EVP_PKEY_PUBLIC_KEY` and `OSSL_PARAM_BLD_push_octet_string(bld, OSSL_PKEY_PARAM_PUB_KEY, .., ..)`.

Format of the uncompressed point is as following:
[0x40] [padded_qx] [padded_qy]
Where 0x40 is a single byte, and `padded_*` are qx and qy padded with leading zeroes to the group size.